# php function called by onchange of html select

Tags: php, function, select, this, onchange

I am learning about php functions and I am having trouble with assigning a new value to a key in a session array based on the users change to a select. (I'm a bit of a noob..).

The select input is part of a `foreach` loop (`foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $players){`. `$players[0]` is a player id number.

Here is the select input:

```
<select name='place" . $players[0] ."' onchange='placechange(". $players[0] .", this)'> 
<option value='5'>5th</option>
<option value='4'>4th</option>
<option value='3'>3rd</option>
<option value='2'>2nd</option>
<option value='1'>1st</option> 
</select>
```

and the function

```
function placechange($id, $pla){
   for ($x = 0; $x < count($_SESSION['results']); $x++){
      if ($_SESSION['results'][$x][0] == $id){
         $_SESSION['results'][$x]['place'] = $pla;
      }
   }
}
```

If the 4th player wins the game, and the select box corresponding to that name is changed to '1st', the desired output is:
`$_SESSION['results'][3]['place'] => 1;` but nothing is changing.

I'm not sure, but I think I am mixing up php functions with js functions? Using a change on the users computer to change an array value that is stored on the server....hmmm..... I guess that doesn't really work...

So how can I use onchange (or similar) to change a php session array value?

Comment: You're mixing JS and PHP together, if you want to monitor an onchange event in your browser and have it set a session variable you need to monitor the event with Javascript and send it to the server with AJAX.

Comment: I thought that might of been the case.
This job is so close to be being finished, just tweaking a few things now and I'm gonna have to go and learn AJAX to finish it... Oh well, I have to learn it sooner or later...Thanks for the tip. If you post that as an answer I'll give you the tick @Dontfeedthecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough example of what you'll need to do to, it's not tested but it'll point you in the right direction:

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['results'] as $players): ?>
<select name="place<?=$players[0] ?>" class="placechange" data-place="<?=$players[0] ?>"> 
<option value="5">5th</option>
<option value="4">4th</option>
<option value="3">3rd</option>
<option value="2">2nd</option>
<option value="1">1st</option> 
</select>
<?php endforeach ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Monitor your selects for change by classname
    $('.placechange').on('change', function() { 

         // Save the place increment and value of the select
         var place = $(this).data('place'),
             value = $(this).val();

         // Send this data to a script somewhere via AJAX
         $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             url: "script.php",
             data: { 
                 place: place,
                 value: value
             }
          })
          .done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          });
    });
});
</script>
```

---

script.php

```
<?php
// This is your function I'm not sure what you're doing here but
// you can send the data to it with the post vars below
function placechange($id, $pla){
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($_SESSION['results']); $x++){
        if ($_SESSION['results'][$x][0] == $id){
            $_SESSION['results'][$x]['place'] = $pla;
        }
    }
}

placechange( $_POST['place'], $_POST['value'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see that you're learning php.

Yes indeed, you're mixing javascript and php which won't work that way.

Any php that you want to use inside javascript/html, you have to inclose them in `<?php ?>` tag.

Sadly you cannot change a php session variable straight in javascript. You will have to send an ajax request to the server which has php, then you assign the session variable there.

**1.**  So inside your placechange() function, add a ajax request with javascript or the jquery library( i suggest jquery, since it's easier) that sends a post request containing the new session value that you want php to assign.

**2.** Then inside the php file, get the post field, and assign that to the respective session variable.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks heaps :) You've shown me very well why it needs to be done this way. Great answer :)

Comment: You're welcome. Keep learning, ask more questions, and you'll be better at it in no time :).